# Angular routing not working when switching component

Tags: angular

I have a problem with my routing. When I reload the site, the table content is there. When I switch to "Add Employee" and back to "Employee List" the content is gone and only the empty table is there.
The problem is probably in app.routing.module.ts. Why does it show the content when path is '', but doesn't when I try to route to 'employees'? I appreciate any help!

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list/employee-list.component';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './create-employee/create-employee.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'employees', component: EmployeeListComponent},
  {path: 'create-employee', component: CreateEmployeeComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'employees', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[When I reload the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVCoL.png)
[When I switch back from "Add Employee"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRA46.png)

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-primary navbar-dark">
    <ul class = "navbar-nav">
        <li class = "nav-item">
            <a routerLink="employees" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link" >Employee List</a>
        </li>
        <li class = "nav-item">
            <a routerLink="create-employee" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link" >Add Employee</a>
        </li>
    </ul> </nav>

<h1 class="text-center"> {{title}} </h1> <div class = "container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet> </div> <footer class = "footer">
    <div class = "container">
        <span>All Rights Reserved 2024 JavaProjects</span>
    </div> </footer>
```

employee-list.component.html

```
<h2> Employee List </h2>
<table class = "table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> First Name </th>
            <th> Last Name </th>
            <th> Email Id </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor = "let employee of employees">
            <td> {{ employee.firstName }} </td>
            <td> {{ employee.lastName }} </td>
            <td> {{ employee.emailId }} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There is a warning when I start the site with "ng serve":
`NG02801: Angular detected that` HttpClient`is not configured to use`fetch`APIs. It's strongly recommended to enable`fetch`for applications that use Server-Side Rendering for better performance and compatibility. To enable`fetch`, add the` withFetch()`to the`provideHttpClient() `call at the root of the application.`

I found a solution: `To do this, just call provideHttpClient(withFetch()) in your app.config.ts.`

My project has no app.config.ts. I tried adding it in "app.module.ts" but there it's called "HttpClientModule"

Comment: my guess is that when you hard fresh the page the data is loading which then renders the table. When you navigate using away and then back again, the data is not loaded the second time. Or the change detection is not updating the view.

Comment: please share the code that shows how you get data and how you bind it to the view.

Comment: @BizzyBob
 I added the code. If you need more, please tell.

Comment: @Harlequin can you share your employee-list.component.ts ?

Comment: How does `employees` variable get populated?  Can you show the controller code?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. I checked the website via "Inspect" and saw several error messages when switchting between the pages. One was:

> employees:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

The Problem was the different ports. 8080 and 4200. Port 8080 got blocked.
I added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` in my springboot-backend in Employee.Controller and that fixed everything. Now I can switch to the employee list and can see all added employees.

Thank you everybody for trying to help me :)
Next time I know to check the console on the website!